# My Mac Mini doesn't wants CD

Tags: hardware, install, mac-mini, dvd, optical-drive

I had a Mac mini. Then the HD broke. So I took an HD from an old Windows notebook. I moved this HD from the Windows notebook to the Mac mini. Now Mac mini correctly starts with Windows XP (what a mess).

So what I want now, is to replace Windows XP with an OS X, but as soon I insert the original Mac mini install disk, my device will spit it out. The same DVD is read on the other Windows computer. Why? What happened? And above all: what can I do????

Comment: At what point is the DVD ejected? Have you tried holding the *alt* (option) key when you turn the machine on until the boot menu appears, and THEN inserted the DVD?

Comment: I've tried to insert the DVD when Mac is started.
If I reboot my computer, with disk inside, holding Alt key, the DVD is ejected and hard drive icon is showed, and if I want I could boot with windows as usual....

Comment: Is this a retail (upgrade/family pack) OSX DVD or did it come with a Mac? If it came with a Mac, are you sure it came with the Mac Mini? You can't install OSX from a disc that came with a Mac on a different type of Mac.

Comment: Yes sure, it is original retail DVD. And anyway every type of CD/DVD is spitted out, even a simple data CD.

Comment: And if you insert the DVD while the boot menu is showing? Do you have a 4+GB USB stick handy? If so you can block-copy the DVD onto the stick. Another option is booting in target disk mode and clearing the HDD using another computer connected via Firewire. (or even installing OSX via firewire if you have another Mac)

Answer (score 1):

Your DVD drive is probably done.
It's usual so what you can do is

1. use external DVD drive or
2. find a friend with a Mac and restore you DVD to 8GB+ flash drive (partitioned as GUID) through Disk Utility or
3. buy the latest Mac OS X (check if your Mini support it though) and restore it to USB flash drive.
4. You can also install Mac OS X on your HDD while put it in external box and using another mac.

Use option key to boot from flash drive.